# flutter getx show dropdown using Provider, Repository, MVC

Tags: flutter, dropdown, flutter-getx

I am new to Flutter, Any one share your idea to show dropdown using getx, I tried listing with List Builder. but don't have idea about dropdown using GetX ( MVC, provider, repository).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare a variable in your controller

var selectedRole = 'CONTENT_CREATOR'.obs;

then declare this method

```
void onSelected(String value) {
selectedRole.value = value;
registrationParam.value.roleType = selectedRole.value;
```

}

finally call from your UI code like this

```
Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, left: 16),
                        child: Obx(
                          () => DropdownButton(
                            underline: SizedBox(),
                            isExpanded: true,
                            hint: Text('Select a role'),
                            value: _regController.selectedRole.value,
                            items: [
                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: "CONTENT_CREATOR",
                                  child: Text("Content Creator")),
                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: "PR", child: Text("PR Agency")),
                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: "JOURNALIST",
                                  child: Text("Journalist"))
                            ],
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              _regController.onSelected(val);
                            },
                          ),
                        )),
```

**Your initial value must be from a value of DropdownMenuItem